# static mapping between ipv6 address and MAC (equivalent to static arp in ipv4)

Tags: networking, ipv6, arp

I want to define in static mapping between ipv6 address and MAC address.(something similar to static arp in ipv4).

(i need to do this because my ubuntu machine is connected by lan to interface that don't use the kernel stack for receiving the packets , and don't know to answer to the ipv6 "neighbor Discovery Protocol" , so i want to config it's the neighbour in a static way)

is it possible?

thanks , 
eyal

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: the ubuntu machine is connected by lan to interface that don't use the kernel stack for receiving the packets , and  don't know to answer to the ipv6  "neighbor Discovery Protocol" , so i want to config it's the neighbour in a static way  ..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Could you please [edit] your post, to add that information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place and the edit will trigger a vote to re-open your question. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Are you looking for `ip -6 neigh add 2001:db8::1 lladdr 00:11:22:33:44:55 nud permanent dev eth1` ?   (obviously changing all parameters to match your devices)